# Is calling ServerSocket.close() sufficient enough to close a port?

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket

I have some java code that looks similar to this:

```
private void startServer() throws IOException {
        URLClassLoader classloader = null;

        System.out.println("Opening server socket for listening on " + PORT_NUMBER);
        try {
            server = new ServerSocket(PORT_NUMBER);
            server.setSoTimeout(10000);
            connected = true;
            System.out.println("Server is now listening on port " + PORT_NUMBER);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Could not start server on port " + PORT_NUMBER);
            e.printStackTrace();
            connected = false;
        }

        while (connected) {

            // Incoming request handler socket.
            Socket socket = null;
            try {
                System.out.println("Waiting for client connection...");
                // Block waiting for an incoming connection.
                socket = server.accept();
                if (socket == null) continue;
```

...and so on and so forth. When I call server.close() later on (I don't get any different behavior if I call socket.close() first), I don't get any errors, but netstat shows that the port is still being listened on. Should calling ServerSocket.close() be sufficient enough to free up the port on this system?

I am programming for a Java 1.4.2 microedition runtime. It is also worthy to note that I have this method being run in another thread, and I am trying to close the socket from its parent thread.

*EDIT* Here is the line from netstat, though I can assure you it is still being listened on, since if I start the Xlet again I get an exception with that port number.

```
tcp        0      0  *.2349                 *.*                    LISTEN
```

Comment: When you say the port is still being listened on, what are you seeing?  Please post the netstat line.

Comment: OT but your 'connected' variable is misnamed. You aren't connected to anything at this point, you are just listening for connections.

Comment: Also OT but `socket` can never be null at the point you are testing it, straight after `accept().` Don't write pointless code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several things to consider. One of them is described by the following quotation from JavaDoc of ServerSocket

> public void setReuseAddress(boolean on)
>                        throws SocketException
>
> Enable/disable the
>   SO_REUSEADDR socket option.  When a TCP connection is closed the
>   connection may remain in a timeout state for a period of time after
>   the connection is closed (typically known as the TIME_WAIT state or
>   2MSL wait state). For applications using a well known socket address
>   or port it may not be possible to bind a socket to the required
>   SocketAddress if there is a connection in the timeout state involving
>   the socket address or port.

So it is kind of OK that the OS can still show that there is something going on after you `close()` the server socket. But if you going to open/close a server socket on the same port frequently you might hit a problem.