# 'Release' a listening ServerSocket in Java

Tags: java, sockets

I have a thread (let's say it's called **ConnListener**) that listens for an incoming connection through a `ServerSocket`'s `accept()` method.

In another thread (call it **StartStopSwitch**) I want the listening thread to be stopped, and no longer listen on the given address and port.

I could kill the thread, using `Thread.interrupt()`, but then when I check the used ports through the `netstat` command, I still see the port with state 'LISTENING'. I want to 'release' (or 'unbind') the `ServerSocket`, without throwing an exception, so it won't show up when using `netstat`.

Now how can I do that?

Comment: [This seems relevant enough](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6769934/is-calling-serversocket-close-sufficient-enough-to-close-a-port)

Comment: You can't kill the thread ith `interrupt().` The `accept()` method isn't interruptible. Just close the socket. You'll get an exception, and you'll just have to live with that.

Comment: @EJP That's an interesting fact, and it's also true. Although [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt%28%29) don't mention it, *`interrupt()` has no effect if the thread is waiting for an interruptible operation, like listening with a `ServerSocket`*. The thread state still is `Thread.State.RUNNABLE`.

Comment: @MCEmperor Facts do tend to be true, whether interesting or otherwise, but `ServerSocket.accept()` isn't an interruptible operation. Only `InterruptibleChannels` have interruptible operations, but they're not much use, as the interrupt closes the channel, due to a Linux peculiarity which had to be propagated to all platforms.

Comment: @EJP Yeah, I see that I made a mistake: "is waiting for an interruptible operation" must be "is waiting for a **non**-interruptible operation".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would not kill/interrupt the thread in which the ServerSocket is listening. Just call close on the ServerSocket from the other thread.

Comment: This answer is the way to go. Make sure the other thread has access to the ServerSocket variable and close it.

Answer (score 0):

As said by [EJP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/207421/ejp), the `accept()` method isn't interruptible, so the **ConnListener** thread I was trying to kill *cannot be killed*, and `interrupt()` has no effect.

Instead, I had to close the ServerSocket by the **StartStopSwitch** thread, causing a `SocketException` to be thrown. It seems that there is no way to tidily close the socket and avoid an exception to be thrown.

```
try {
    Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
}
catch (SocketException exc) {
    // SocketException is thrown when serverSocket is closed.
}
finally {
    // You don't have to close the socket, because in order to
    // reach this block, another thread had to close the socket.

    //serverSocket.close();
}
```

See [this Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6769934/is-calling-serversocket-close-sufficient-enough-to-close-a-port) for more details.

Comment: @user207421 It took me 4½ years. ;-)